# Cannot export to CSV after data alignment

Tags: python, pandas

I have two sets of data and only want to keep the data where both sets have common dates. I imported the data sets with `read_csv()`, calling them *`df1`*, *`df2`*.

Then run:

```
DF=df1.align(df2, join='inner',axis=0)
```

After checking, it appears that *DF* is a tuple. The goal is to export the aligned data (on common dates only) using `DF.to_csv(path)`. It fails with the message that 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_csv'. I don't understand why the join has created a tuple. Shouldn't this still be a dataframe that can be exported to a CSV?

Is there a better command to use, so that it can easily be exported to a .csv file?

Comment: What's a "dataframe"? If you're referring to tools outside the Python standard library, please be explicit about what they are and where they're from.

Comment: Are you using rpy to get a dataframe?

Comment: I'm using the pandas library and iPython console.

Answer (score 2):

`align` returns aligned versions of the left and right DataFrames (as a tuple):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#aligning-objects-with-each-other-with-align

Answer (score 1):

Read the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.align.html?highlight=dataframe#pandas.DataFrame.align).

```
DF,type = df1.align(df2, join='inner', axis=0)
DF.to_csv(path)
```

Comment: Thank you. I set type=DataFrame. 

When I export the csv--it gives back the *original* data set df1( & vice versa for if df1 and df2 are swapped in the align command). IE, it is not merging the data sets on common dates (index). Is there a reason one shouldn't use align for this task?

Comment: @user1374969 Align, I would imagine, simply arranges the data. 
Not unlike a sort command, but I don't know, give it a shot. I'd print out both sets of data after aligning them. I assume they will line up nicely.